# What happens if I realloc to smaller size?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, libc

I'm currently studying dynamic memory allocation and I've got a question on realloc function.
I've learned that the contents of the newly allocated block should be same as those of the old block, up to the minimum of the old and new size, and everything else is uninitialized.

What if the heap block is using boundary tag, and I am reallocating to smaller size?

What I'm asking is, for example, here's a 24-bytes-sized memory block whose first 4 bytes are the header, 16 bytes in the middle are payload, and last 4 bytes are the footer. And I've shrinked this block to 16 bytes, whose first 4 bytes will be header of new block and last 4 bytes will be footer of new block.

First, does header change? Header should be including information about block size and alloc bit, but contents of new block should be same. Does this mean all contents including block size information in header remain same, which seems totally useless for me?

Secondly, how should I put the footer of new block? The footer should take place at 13th ~ 16th bytes of new block. But the contents of new and old block should be the same up to 16 bytes, which is violated if I put the footer at 13th ~ 16th bytes!

Sorry for such a wordy question, but I'm very very confused right now.
Hopefully I could find an answer.

---

additional info about question)

I am currently working on malloc lab from CS:APP, which wants me to design an allocator by writing my own version of malloc, free, and realloc routines. And it says these functions should match the semantics of corresponding libc malloc, free, and realloc routines.

Right now I'm actually implementing my own realloc function, and I became confused about those situations. So I hope I can get C standard library implementation level answer.

Comment: This depends *very* much on the allocator used, and also on the operating systems own allocator used beneath `malloc` and `realloc`. And if you're learning about dynamic allocation from an applications point of view, there's really no need to know any of this low-level implementation-specific stuff. So please expand your question to tell us at what level you're studying this, application level, C Standard library implementation level, or operating system level.

Comment: The "header" and "footer" are CRT implementation internals. As far as the app code goes, all it sees and manipulates is what you call the "payload". If that was 16 bytes and you realloc to 8 bytes, then the contents of those 8 bytes is guaranteed to match the previous 8 bytes. What happens on the inside with the header/footer is immaterial, unless you happen to be writing the CRT heap management code.

Comment: If you have shrunk the block from 24 bytes to 16, the last 8 bytes were lost. Function `realloc()` can't know your intended use. The remaining 16 bytes preserve whatever values they had previously.

Comment: You could study the [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). On Linux, it implements `malloc` and `realloc` above [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep the first `size` bytes of the buffer.

I saw a `realloc()` that would just lop the end off and construct a new free heap block with the end of the buffer.

I saw another `realloc()` that would move the buffer to the end and lop the front off.

I saw yet another `realloc()` that would always allocate a new buffer and move the memory.

Stranger things can happen, I'm sure of it.

Sometimes `realloc()` concludes that cutting a few bytes of the end isn't worth it and doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: I actually have to implement my own realloc routine, so do you mean I can just decide what to do on those kind of situations?

Comment: @이호영: Yup. Comes down to just read the specification from either side.